# Why is onSubmit is not called in my code?

Tags: java, wicket

`onSubmit()` isn't called in a WebPage.

I've already tried it with `super.onSubmit()`, I've tried to implement it with a Button.

And and I know for sure that it isn't called, because tries to sysout some `String`s in the code in the `onSubmit` - Method.

Here's the Code:

```
Form form = new Form("setPersonalDataForm") {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
              System.out.println("If you read this its called");
            String setPersonalDataEndpoint = new PropertyLoader().getPropValues("setPersonalData", "api.properties");

            JSONObject setPersonalDataJson = new JSONObject();

            Object uasAccountId = uasAccountIdTextField.getDefaultModelObject();
            Object firstname = firstnameTextField.getDefaultModelObject();
            Object middlename = middlenameTextField.getDefaultModelObject();
            Object surname = surnameTextField.getDefaultModelObject();
            Object companyline1 = companyLine1TextField.getDefaultModelObject();
            Object companyline2 = companyLine2TextField.getDefaultModelObject();

            String dateToConvert = birthdateTextField.getDefaultModelObject().toString();

            DateConverter dateConverter = (date) -> {

                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d H:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                ZonedDateTime parsedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateToConvert, formatter);
                DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Object birthdate = parsedDate.format(formatter2);

                return birthdate.toString();
            };

            Object birthdate = dateConverter.convertDate(dateToConvert);

            setPersonalDataJson.put("brand", selectedBrand);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("uasAccountId", uasAccountId);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("salutation", selectedSalutation);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("gender", selectedGender);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("firstname", firstname);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("middlename", middlename);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("surname", surname);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("companyLine1", companyline1);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("companyLine2", companyline2);
            setPersonalDataJson.put("birthday", birthdate);


            PageParameters setPersonalDataParameters = new PageParameters();

            try {

                ResponseEntity response = new TestService().postTestJson(setPersonalDataJson, setPersonalDataEndpoint);

                String responseBody = response.getBody().toString();

                JSONObject responseJsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                String testSuccessfull = responseJsonObject.get("status").toString();
                String message = responseJsonObject.get("message").toString();

                setPersonalDataParameters.add("testSuccessfull", testSuccessfull);
                setPersonalDataParameters.add("message", message);
                setPersonalDataParameters.add("requestJson", setPersonalDataJson.toString());
                setResponsePage(ResponsePage.class, setPersonalDataParameters);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                setPersonalDataParameters.add("testSuccessfull", "failed");
                setPersonalDataParameters.add("requestJson", setPersonalDataJson.toString());
            }
            setResponsePage(ResponsePage.class, setPersonalDataParameters);
        }
    };
```

Does anyone know why it isn't called and how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure because printl isn't a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `onSubmit()` is not called then most probably `onError()` is called!

One of items in the "Best practices" slide of my Apache Wicket training is: always override `onError()` together with `onSubmit()`! Most of the time you will want to re-render a FeedbackPanel in its body. But even printing something to stderr will save you a lot of frustrations!

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain to me why onSubmit isnt called but onError? Or can you send me a link?

Comment: @XaNaX420 This is very well described in the official Wicket documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_default_form_processing